# пагинация Django

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Как в Django (1.7) сделать пагинацию с отступами (хз как это назвать) ?
Пример: 1...6 7 **8** 9 10...100
В рунете заискался не нашел нормального решения. А с английским у меня не очень...
На данный момент:
views.py

```
def articles(request):
    list_articles = Article.objects.filter(moderated=True).order_by("-created")
    paginator = Paginator(list_articles, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        list_articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        list_articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        list_articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if page == "1":
        return redirect('articles')

    template_dict = {'articles': list_articles}
    return render(request, 'perfectfit/list_articles.html', template_dict)
```

list_articles.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
 {% for article in articles %}
   <a class="list-group-item" href="{% url 'article' article.id %}">{{article.title}}</a>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
<div class="text-center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if articles.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ articles.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled">
        <a href="">&laquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for page in articles.paginator.page_range %}
      <li class="{% if articles.number == page %}active{% endif %} page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if articles.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ articles.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><a href="">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для примера кусок из моего старого кода:

```
<div class="page-nav">
    {% if paginator.page.has_previous %}
    <!-- Показывам кнопку со ссылкой, если есть предыдущая страница -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.previous_page_number %}">&lt;&nbsp; Вперед</a>
    {% else %}
    <!-- Показываем неактивную кнопку, если предыдущей страницы нет -->
    <span>&lt;&nbsp; Вперед</span>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Прибавляем к номеру текущей страницы -4 (т.е. отнимаем 4) -->
    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'-4' > 0 %} 
    <!-- Если до текущей страницы есть больше 4 страниц, показываем многоточие -->
    <span class="ellipsis">...</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'-3' > 0 %}
    <!-- Если до текущей страницы есть ещё три страницы -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.number|add:'-3' %}">{{ paginator.page.number|add:'-3' }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'-2' > 0 %}
    <!-- Если до текущей страницы есть ещё две страницы -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.number|add:'-2' %}">{{ paginator.page.number|add:'-2' }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'-1' > 0 %}
    <!-- Если до текущей страницы есть ещё одна страница -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.number|add:'-1' %}">{{ paginator.page.number|add:'-1' }}</a>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Номер текущей страницы -->
    <span>{{ paginator.page.number }}</span>

    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'1' <= paginator.num_pages %}
    <!-- Если после текущей страницы есть ещё одна страница -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.number|add:'1' %}">{{ paginator.page.number|add:'1' }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'2' <= paginator.num_pages %}
    <!-- Если после текущей страницы есть ещё две страницы -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.number|add:'2' %}">{{ paginator.page.number|add:'2' }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'3' <= paginator.num_pages %}
    <!-- Если после текущей страницы есть ещё три страницы -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.number|add:'3' %}">{{ paginator.page.number|add:'3' }}</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if paginator.page.number|add:'4' <= paginator.num_pages %}
    <!-- Если после текущей страницы есть ещё четыре страницы -->
    <span class="ellipsis">...</span>
    {% endif %}    

    {% if paginator.page.has_next %}
    <!-- Показывам кнопку со ссылкой, если есть следующая страница -->
    <a href="{% url 'newslines:show_page' paginator.page.next_page_number %}">Назад &nbsp;&gt;</a>
    {% else %}
    <!-- Если нет следующей страницы -->
    <span>Назад &nbsp;&gt;</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Получается вот такая пагинация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать пакет [django-bootstrap-pagination](https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination).

Краткая информация об использовании:

Установка:

```
pip install django-bootstrap-pagination
```

Добавим в `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'bootstrap_pagination',
)
```

В шаблоне:

```
{% load bootstrap_pagination %}
```

Теперь что-бы отобразить 10 элементов на странице с сылками на первую и последнюю страницу можно сделать так:

```
{% bootstrap_paginate page_obj range=10 show_prev_next="false" show_first_last="true" %}
```

Дополнительная информация в [документации](https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination).