# Как ограничить количество страниц в пагинации?

Tags: django

На странице есть пагинация, выводится определенное число записей на каждой. Чем больше общее число записей , тем больше выводится страниц пагинатора. Необходимо ограничить число выводимых страниц до определенного значения (допустим 3). Чтобы выглядело примерно так:

- **1** 2 3
- 1 **2** 3
- 2 **3** 4
- 3 **4** 5

Мой код:

Django:

```
def all_photos(request, number_photo, number_page=1):
    ads= Ads.objects.get(pk=number_photo)
    list_url_not_pagin= [url for url in ads.images.all()]
    list_url= Paginator(list_url_not_pagin, 1).page(number_page)
    ad_pk= ads.pk
    context = {'description':ads.description, 'list_url':list_url, 'ad_pk':ad_pk}
    return render(request, 'main/all_photos.html', context)
```

Шаблонизатор:

```
    {%for page in list_url.paginator.page_range%}
        <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk page%}"><strong>{{page}}</strong></a></li>
    {%endfor%}
```

Как указать ограничение, чтобы при большом количестве записей не было что-то типа

**1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15..

Благодарю

***Если кому-то интересно решение, к которому я прибегнул, вот код:***

```
{% if list_url.number|add:'1' > list_url.paginator.num_pages and list_url.number|add:'-4' > 0 %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'-4'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'-4'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if list_url.number|add:'2' > list_url.paginator.num_pages  and list_url.number|add:'-3' > 0 %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'-3'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'-3'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if list_url.number|add:'-2' > 0 %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'-2'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'-2'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if list_url.number|add:'-1' > 0 %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'-1'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'-1'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            <li><a class='pagin_page'><span><strong>{{list_url.number}}</strong></span></a></li>

            {% if list_url.number|add:'1' <= list_url.paginator.num_pages %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'1'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'1'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if list_url.number|add:'2' <= list_url.paginator.num_pages %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'2'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'2'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if list_url.number|add:'-2' <= 0 and list_url.number|add:'3' <= list_url.paginator.num_pages %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'3'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'3'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if list_url.number|add:'-1' <= 0 and list_url.number|add:'4' <= list_url.paginator.num_pages %}
              <li><a class='pagin' href="{%url 'all_photos_page' ad_pk list_url.number|add:'4'%}#images">{{list_url.number|add:'4'}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
```

Объяснение вы можете найти по ссылке в комментарии под этим постом. Там расписана каждая строчка. Я взял общую идею оттуда, но добавил некоторые условия в шаблон, которые были нужны для более правильного отображения

Comment: посмотрите этот ответ, там с комментариями описана пагинация https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834369/355827

Comment: Спасибо, полезно

Comment: вам надо было оставить ответ на свой вопрос, а не добавить ответ в вопрос.