# Не получается нормально реализовать пагинацию Django

Tags: python, django

Такое дело, сверстал пагинацию, у которой есть начальная часть и конечная. В начальной нужно чтобы отображались цифры до 9 страницы, и чтобы когда пользователь кликнет на 7 страницу, после этого в пагинации пропала 1 страница и появилась 10 страница.

Вот фотка как сейчас это выглядит на 1 странице:
https://ibb.co/QMsdZcq

А вот что происходит при наведении на конечную часть пагинации:
https://ibb.co/yQCWVyg

По идее после 6 страницы должна была появится 10 страница, а 1 пропасть, но происходит вот так(это на 7 странице):
https://ibb.co/TTntV2C

И вот собственно как должно быть(также на 7 странице):
https://ibb.co/61PYv7r

И то же самое с конечной частью.

Вот часть пагинации в шаблоне:

```
<!-- НАЧАЛЬНАЯ ЧАСТЬ -->
<div class="pb-start" style="left: 0px;">
  <nav>
    <ul>

      {% for n in page_object.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_object.number == n and n < 10 %}
          <li>
            <a class="paginator__num current" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a>
          </li>
        {% elif n < 10 %}
          <li>
            <a class="paginator__num" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a>
          </li>
        {% elif n > page_object.number|add:-6 and n < page_object.number|add:4 %}
          <li>
            <a class="paginator__num" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- КОНЕЧНАЯ ЧАСТЬ -->
<div class="pb-end">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      {% for n in page_object.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_object.number == n and n > 9 %}
          <li>
            <a class="paginator__num current" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a>
          </li>
        {% elif n > 9 %}
          <li>
            <a class="paginator__num" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a>
          </li>
        {% comment %} {% elif n > page_object.number|add:-6 and n < page_object.number|add:4 %}
          <li>
            <a class="paginator__num" href="?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a>
          </li> {% endcomment %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

И пагинация во views.py:

```
def index(request):

    ...

    paginator = Paginator(softs, 2)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    is_paginated = page.has_other_pages()

    ...

    context = {..., 'page_object': page, 'is_paginated': is_paginated}
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

**Всем откликнувшимся заранее спасибо.**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834369/355827

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы в начале отображалось 9 страниц, и только после 6 это все срабатывало?